# Discrepancy between the tableView and Realm database

Tags: ios, uitableview, realm

While implementing swipe-to-delete feature I'm facing the following problem:
When I delete the item, the last item from the array occupies its place.

So for example I have the array [1,2,3,4,5]. After deletion of 2 (index 1), the array in the database looks this [1,5,3,4]. But the table view displays everything correct [1,3,4,5]. Why is it so? I want Realm items to be saved this way [1,3,4,5].

Below if the function implementation:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            try! realm.write {
                let itemToDelete = items[indexPath.row]

                realm.delete(itemToDelete)

            }
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Top)
        }
    }
```

I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: If the items in the table view are displaying correctly ("1, 3, 4, 5"), how do you know they are being stored incorrectly in the Realm? I tried reproducing your behavior, but I can't. If you could add more code to your question, including how your Realm models are set up and how your table view is using those models, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @AustinZ I use Realm Browser to see how the database behaves. Thanks to answers below I see what was my sorting issue.

Answer (score 3):

Please keep in mind that `Results` aren't guaranteed to preserve order of insertion. For performance reasons, items may be reordered to keep the Realm file small, or to keep operations fast.

`List` properties *are* guaranteed to preserve their order of insertion.

If you want stable ordering of your `Results`, make sure to sort them.

This is covered in Realm's docs on [sorting](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#sorting).

Comment: Thank you! Now I see the difference between Results and List and why I had that sorting issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `realm.delete` rather than `myList.remove`, I assume that `itemToDelete` is a stand-alone object rather than an instance in a Realm List. The sequence of items in a Realm List is guaranteed, but not for retrieval of objects. Therefore if you're just using `realm.objects`, the sequence cannot be guaranteed, unless you apply your own filter.

I assume you're using Realm Browser and expecting the sequence to match, which it won't.

Comment: Thanks! I've realized that I need to use List or sort my Results.